# pygeocoder module is not working

Tags: python, gis, geocoding

Hello I am trying to geocode German companies addresses. My file is a csv file with 2 columns the addresses that I want to geocode and number of employees. When I load the file, using pandas, and print the  addresses they are properly displayed (so I think it is not an encoding issue) even though they have some german characters. This is my code:

```
import csv
import pygeocoder
import pandas as pd
import codecs
import json
import urllib2
from pygeocoder import Geocoder

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Jtrujillo\Desktop\germangeocodes (2).csv')

address = df.Address
print address

for a in address:
    result = Geocoder.geocode(a)
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "F:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pygeocoder.py", line 110, in geocode
    return GeocoderResult(Geocoder.get_data(params=params))
  File "F:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pygeocoder.py", line 190, in get_data
    raise GeocoderError(response_json['status'], response.url)
pygeolib.GeocoderError: Error INVALID_REQUEST
Query: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=&region=&bounds=&components=&address=Marcel-Breuer-Str.+12%2C+M%FCnchen%2C+Bayern%2C+80807%2C+Germany&sensor=false
```

This is the file i am using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tynzlc9wp74zszr/germangeocodes%20%282%29.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell pandas the encoding of your file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('geocodes.csv', encoding="iso-8859-1")
```

Comment: This works great, thanks a lot. Do you always have to specify to pygeocoder the encoding of the file?

Comment: Good question. Only if it's something non-standard which causes problems. :)